TypeScript error: Type '{ children: ReactNode; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes' in dynamic React component
I am trying to create a React component in TypeScript, and I want to have a dynamic component that will wrap each of the child nodes that are passed to my component. The component is called Slider and here's how I want it to work:

Children are passed to the component

<Slider wrapper='div'>
    <p>Slide 1</p>
    <p>Slide 2</p>
    <p>Slide 3</p>
</Slider>


Component logic wraps each child node in whatever component/string passed to the Slider component. If you pass:

<Slider wrapper='div'>...</Slider>

You'll get:
<div>
    <p>Slide 1</p>
</div>

And if you pass:
<Slider wrapper={MyComponent}>...</Slider>

You'll get:
<MyComponent>
    <p>Slide 1</p>
</MyComponent>

I wanted to be able to accept all the props within the component and then render everything with logic inside the component, but I keep getting a Typescript error:

Type { children: ReactNode; } has no properties in common with type IntrinsicAttributes. ts(2559)

I've looked at some other Stack Overflow questions and some Github issues, but I haven't found solutions that help with my problem. I could certainly be overthinking or glossing over something obvious, so whatever help you can offer, I'm willing to hear!
Here's my component code so far:
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";

type SliderProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    wrapper?: string | (() => ReactElement);
}>;

export default function Slider({
    children,
    wrapper: Wrapper = "div",
}: SliderProps) {
    return <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>; // error on this line under <Wrapper>
}


You just need to use a more specific type than string so the compiler knows it's limited to valid HTML tag names:
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

type SliderProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    wrapper?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | (() => JSX.Element);
}>;

export default function Slider({
    children,
    wrapper: Wrapper = "div",
}: SliderProps) {
    return <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>;
}

Note that the Typescript JSX namespace is ambient, you don't have to import it as long as you've imported React itself.
Playground

TypeScript expects the wrapper prop to be a string that refers to an HTML element or a React component type, but it’s not able to infer the correct type for Wrapper when you try to use it as a component.
To fix this, you can define the wrapper prop to be of type React.ElementType, which is a built-in type that React provides for representing a component that can be rendered.
Here’s how you can adjust your SliderProps type and Slider component:
import { PropsWithChildren, ElementType } from "react";

type SliderProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    wrapper?: ElementType;
}>;

export default function Slider({
    children,
    wrapper: Wrapper = "div",
}: SliderProps) {
    return <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>;
}


I don't think you can just swap out a string for a component.   I believe this is more appropriate.
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";

type SliderProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    wrapper?: string | (() => ReactElement);
}>;

type SliderProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    wrapper?: (() => ReactElement);
}>;


export default function Slider({
    children,
    wrapper: Wrapper ,
}: SliderProps) {
    if(Wrapper) return <Wrapper>{children}</Wrapper>
    return <div>{children}</div>
}


You absolutely can swap out a string for a component... if it's an HTML tag name like 'div' or 'a'. Remember the JSX gets compiled to a call to React.createElement which uses strings for native HTML tags. You can also see it in the compiled output in the TS playground link from my answer.
